# Why is setTimout displaying a random integer in browser for the duration of timout when rendering react component and how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call a setTimeout in my render method to display a message for a couple of seconds before redirecting and everything works as should except for a random integer which I am assuming is the setTimout Id received. How can I remove this number/id from displaying?

```
if(this.props.submitted === 'SUCCESS') {
   return (
     <div>
        ...
        ...
        <div className="...">
        {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
            }, 20000);
          }
        </div>
     </div>
   )
} else {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just execute your setTimeout before return

Comment: Don’t quite understand the problem, you receive message from server then you put it in state, or prop and then display it... setTimeout should not be part of your return anyway

Comment: Yeah it is true :) lazy, you know :) when I got to write about why - other answers were already there

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to note here:

1. setTimeout returns a unique `timeoutId` which is what you're seeing displayed.
2. you shouldn't put setTimeout inside of a render function nor in the returned jsx from a functional component, because every single time the component re-renders you will be calling setTimeout again which is probably not your desired outcome. Instead, put the setTimeout inside of a `useEffect` for a functional component, or inside `componentDidMount` for a class component.

Answer (score 1):

Funny question
Short answer: there is no problem
Long answer: when you set a timeout, or an interval, an id(yes, that number) is returned. Why is the id returned? To be able to clear the timeout or interval. Let me show you an example of the returned id

```js
var timer1=setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log("this message will never show")
},10000)//10 seconds

var i=1

var interval1=setInterval(()=>{
  console.log(i)
  if(i>7){
    console.log("sikeee, I END IT NOW")
    clearTimeout(timer1)
    clearInterval(interval1)
  }i++
},1000)//1 second
```

Comment: You are correct it moving it outside of the render fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Putting the setTimeout inside of componentDidMount and clearing it on componentWillUnmount did the trick.

```
componentDidMount() {

  if(this.props.submitted === 'SUCCESS') {
    timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
               this.props.history.push('/');
             }, 5000)
  } 
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(timer1);
}
```